# Show a random div upon click except the current one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I made a simple quote slider that changes the sentence on the screen randomly upon each click, but I don't want it to show the same quote twice in a row. How can I exclude the current quote from the `Math.random` algorithm and make the slider show any other quote upon each click?

(I don't want each quote to be shown only once, I just want to prevent the slider to show the same one in a row)

HTML:

```
<div class="container" onclick="changequote()">
    <div class="quote">Sentence 1</div>
    <div class="quote">Sentence 2</div>
    <div class="quote">Sentence 3</div>
</div>
<script>window.onload = changequote()</script>
```

JS:

```
function changequote() {
   var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.quote').length);
   $('.quote').hide().eq(random).fadeTo(500, 1);
}
```

CSS:

```
.quote {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could toggle a class to track the `current` quote. Then randomly pick from the quotes that are `:not(.current)`.

Also I moved the javascript to the javascript section, which really helps for maintainability. Nothing like pouring through the .js file when debugging just to find out the issue is originating from the html.

```js
function changequote() {       
  let $quotes = $('.quote:not(.current)');

  $('.quote').removeClass('current').hide(); //reset all quotes
   
  $quotes //pick from all quotes except the previously selected one
    .eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $quotes.length)) 
    .addClass('current')
    .fadeIn();
}

$('.container').on('click', changequote).click(); //click will initialize on page load
```

```css
.quote{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="quote">Sentence 1</div>
  <div class="quote">Sentence 2</div>
  <div class="quote">Sentence 3</div>
  <div class="quote">Sentence 4</div>
  <div class="quote">Sentence 5</div>
  <div class="quote">Sentence 6</div>
  <div class="quote">Sentence 7</div>
  <div class="quote">Sentence 8</div>
  <div class="quote">Sentence 9</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great solution, thank you! It sometimes leaves more than one quotes in the screen when I click fast. So I replaced your `fadeIn()` with my `fadeTo(500, 1)` and problem solved :) I click the accepted answer button now. Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm, never shows more than one for me. You can use [.finish()](https://api.jquery.com/finish/) if you want more control of the animation queue.  [.fadeIn()](https://api.jquery.com/fadein/), like [.fadeTo()](https://api.jquery.com/fadeto/) takes a duration as the first argument. So `fadeIn(500)` is the same as `fadeTo(500, 1)`, the difference being fadeIn sets `display: block, opacity: 1` whereas fadeTo doesn't change the display rule and sets the opacity to the value you give it.

Comment: Not sure this works "//pick from all quotes except the previously selected one" because you "//reset all quotes" in the same function. As a result, previously selected ones can appear as the next item. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

Just save the index into a global variable, using closures

```
const changeQuote = (() => {
  let lastSelectedIndex;
  return function() {
     let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.quote').length);
     while(true)
     {
       random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.quote').length);
       if(random !== lastSelectedIndex) break;
     }
     $('.quote').eq(lastSelectedIndex).hide();
     $('.quote').eq(random).fadeIn(500);
     lastSelectedIndex = random;
  }
})();
```

**EDIT:** Here is a running example

```js
const changeQuote = (() => {
  let lastSelectedIndex;
  return function() {
     let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.quote').length);
     while(true)
     {
       random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.quote').length);
       if(random !== lastSelectedIndex) break;
     }
     $('.quote').eq(lastSelectedIndex).hide();
     $('.quote').eq(random).fadeIn(500);
     lastSelectedIndex = random;
  }
})();
```

```css
.quote {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="quote">Sentence 1</div>
<div class="quote">Sentence 2</div>
<div class="quote">Sentence 3</div>

<button onclick="changeQuote()">Show Random Quote</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I replaced my js code with yours and unfortunately didn't work. It doesn't show any quote upon page load or upon click. Do you maybe know why? (Btw in my code .quote style is `display:none` by default)

Comment: Just added a working sample.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to make it work with my code, but there are some issues... 1) If I click the button fast, it doesn't hide the previous quote in time, so it sometimes leaves more than one quotes in the screen... 2) I need to call the codes through `function changequote()` in js... 3) I need to use `onclick` and `onload` together. I made a little addition in the html code to make it clear, please see.

Comment: `while(true)`?!? I can't think of any reason you would ever run a while(true) client side, you're just asking to lock up their system.

Comment: It’s not an infinite loop. It’s a loop with a condition. Like any other. And it’s very unlikely the code chooses the same number over and over again. So it’s not blocking.